# Is there something in this code block that would stop execution?

Tags: php

I am parsing a webpage and following the links in order to map links from one page to another. I am only pulling the title of the page the link is on, the URL used to link the pages, and the title of the page the URL leads to.

My code works smoothly to discover the links I am interested in and descends subpages to find additional product links. There are a few hundred of these across at least a hundred pages, so it's several HTML files of parsing. I am building an in the form `$products[index]` contains is an array `array(['url'] => URLToPage, ['title'] => TitleOfPage, ['link_title'] => TitleOfLinkedPage)` as I hope this demonstrates.

The script works fine until I add this snippet, after which the script will stop execution with no errors, warnings, notices or anything; it simply never reaches the end of the script. I have included `set_time_limit(0)` to prevent execution time from expiring as this script takes some time to complete. This code is executed after the $products array has been populated, if any links found, and $products is always an array, and I have outputted the $link_html_strings in test cases to verify that the pages are being retrieved as expected. This is the offending code:

```
// Populate the destination link titles
if ( isset( $products ) && count( $products ) > 0 )
    {
        foreach( $products as $id => $product )
        {
             $from_this_page = $product['url'];
             if ( $DEBUG ) echo 'Parsing ' . $from_this_page . '.<br />';
             $link_html_string = file_get_contents( $from_this_page, NULL, NULL, NULL, 500 );
             $string_parts = explode( '<title>', $link_html_string );
             $string_parts = explode( '</title>', $string_parts[1] );
             $products[$id]['link_title'] = $string_parts[0];
             if ( $DEBUG ) echo 'Found title: ' . $products[$id]['link_title'] . '<br />';
             ob_flush();
             flush();
        }
    }
```

There should never really be 500 characters needed, however, I had some concern with memory usage when reading the entire files so I reduced the load (I think) by limiting the read. I thought perhaps the script was using up all the allocated memory for PHP. When this is included, it will iterate through this loop several times but at some point stop execution, this point is not also exactly the same. I will get several echo for what file is being parsed.

This is the full code for the script, included to answer questions regarding contents of $products in comments.

```
<?php
// PHP HTML DOM Parser from http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/
require_once( 'includes/simple_html_dom.php' );

//error_reporting( E_ALL );
set_time_limit( 0 );

// Debugging flag
$DEBUG = false;

function reportProducts( $category, $products )
{
    echo '<table width="90%" align="center"><tr><th colspan="3">';
    echo $category . ' has ' . count( $products ) . ' products listed, or in subpages.';
    echo '</th></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td bgcolor="#777777" width="30%">This page</td>
        <td bgcolor="#bbbbbb" width="30%">links with</td>
        <td bgcolor="#777777" width="30%">to this page</td></tr>';
    foreach( $products as $product )
    {
        echo '<tr><td bgcolor="#777777">' . $product['title'] . '</td>
            <td bgcolor="#bbbbbb"><a href="' . $product['url'] . '">' . $product['url'] . 
            '</a></td><td bgcolor="#777777">' . $product['link_title'] . '</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</table><br />';
    ob_flush(); // Server may buffer again, preventing incremental display
    flush();
}

function parseProductsForPage( $page_to_parse )
{
    global $DEBUG;
    $failed = false;
    $product_id = 0;
    $page_dom = new simple_html_dom();
    $page_html_string = @file_get_contents( $page_to_parse->href );
    $load_state = @$page_dom->load( $page_html_string );
    if ( $load_state === NULL )
    {
        // Find any direct product pages for this page
        if ( $DEBUG ) echo $page_to_parse->href . ' being checked for products... ';
        $possible = $page_dom->find( 'a[onclick]' );
            foreach( $possible as $link )
            {
                if ( $link->innertext == "[ Add to cart ]" )
                {
                    $products[$product_id]['url'] = $link->href;
                    $titles = $page_dom->find( 'title' );
                    $products[$product_id]['title'] = $titles[0]->innertext;
                    $product_id++;
                }
            }
        if ( $DEBUG ) 
        {
            if ( isset( $products ) )
            {
                echo count( $products ) . ' found on page.<br />';
            } else
            {
                echo '0 found on page.<br />';
            }
        }

        // Find subpages...
        if ( $DEBUG ) echo $page_to_parse->href . ' being checked for links... ';
        $subpages = $page_dom->find( 'a[class=buy]' );
        if ( $DEBUG ) echo count( $subpages ) . ' found.<br />';
        // ... and parse
        foreach( $subpages as $subpage )
        {
            $subpage_dom = new simple_html_dom();
            $subpage_html_string = @file_get_contents( $subpage->href );
            $load_state = @$subpage_dom->load( $subpage_html_string );
            if ( $load_state === NULL )
            {
                // Find any direct product pages for this page
                if ( $DEBUG ) echo $subpage->href . ' being checked for products... ';
                $possible = $subpage_dom->find( 'a[onclick]' );
                    foreach( $possible as $link )
                    {
                        if ( $link->innertext == "[ Add to cart ]" )
                        {
                            $products[$product_id]['url'] = $link->href;
                            $titles = $page_dom->find( 'title' );
                            $products[$product_id]['title'] = $titles[0]->innertext;
                            $product_id++;
                        }
                    }
                if ( $DEBUG ) 
                {
                    if ( isset( $products ) )
                    {
                        echo count( $products ) . ' found on page.<br />';
                    } else
                    {
                        echo '0 found on page.<br />';
                    }
                }
                $subpage_dom->clear();
            } else
            {
                $failed[] = $subpage->href;
            }
            $subpage_dom->clear();
            unset( $subpage_dom );
        }
        // Populate the destination link titles
        if ( isset( $products ) && count( $products ) > 0 )
        {
            foreach( $products as $id => $product )
            {
                // $from_this_page = $product['url'];
                // if ( $DEBUG ) echo 'Parsing ' . $from_this_page . '.<br />';
                // $link_html_string = file_get_contents( $from_this_page, NULL, NULL, NULL, 500 );
                // $string_parts = explode( '<title>', $link_html_string );
                // $string_parts = explode( '</title>', $string_parts[1] );
                // $products[$id]['link_title'] = $string_parts[0];
                // if ( $DEBUG ) echo 'Found title: ' . $products[$id]['link_title'] . '<br />';
                // ob_flush();
                // flush();
            }
        }
    } else
    {
        $failed[] = $page_to_parse->href;
    }
    $titles = $page_dom->find( 'title' );
    if ( isset( $products ) ) reportProducts( $titles[0]->innertext, $products );
    $page_dom->clear();
    unset( $page_dom );
    return $failed;
}

// Initialize the object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file( 'index.html' );

// Start output buffer
ob_start();

// Find all product categories listed on the website
if ( $DEBUG ) echo '<h1>Collecting links from LHN...</h1>';
$sidelinks = $html->find( 'a[class=sidelink_main]' );
$html->clear();
unset( $html );

echo '<h1>Found ' . count( $sidelinks ) . ' categories.</h1><br />';
ob_flush(); // Server may buffer output, preventing incremental display
flush();

// Find links and products for each category
foreach( $sidelinks as $sidelink )
{
    if ( $DEBUG ) echo 'Sending ' . $sidelink->href . ' to parser.<br />';
    $parse_failed = parseProductsForPage( $sidelink );
    if ( $parse_failed )
    {
        foreach( $parse_failed as $failure )
        {
            $failures[] = $failure;
        }
    }
}

echo count( $failures ) . ' pages failed to parse.<br />';

echo '<br />FIN!<br />'; // Easily searched to verfiy end of script was reached, also
                         // celebratory.
ob_end_flush(); // Clear output buffer
flush();
?>
```

Comment: I take it `$DEBUG` has a true-like value? Assuming that this is the case, whatever the problem is obviously must occur before the conditional `echo` statement the first time through the loop.

Comment: Also an irrelevant point, I'm pretty sure the `&& count( $products ) > 0` bit is unnecessary as the `foreach` loop just loops zero times if the array is empty.

Comment: @Hammerite Am I under the mistaken impression that the conditional statement `if ( $DEBUG ) echo ...;` doesn't only effect that line? As in, despite the value of `$DEBUG` (which is true/false) the line `$link_html_string = file_get_contents(...);` will be executed?

Comment: Correction, the conditional statement _does_ only effect that line in my understanding.

Comment: In my opinion braces should always be used with control statements, as it improves the clarity of the code and makes mistakes less likely.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that set_time_limit has any effect (when running php with safe_mode on it will not have any effect )?

Also be sure that `$string_parts = explode( '<title>', $link_html_string );`  gives an result(there may be no title-element or the tagName may be used uppercase)

Comment: I am not 100% sure that the `set_time_limit` has an effect, I will look up how to determine if safe_mode is on and see if this is the issue. When `$DEBUG = true` the script does echo several lines of correct strings for expected titles. I can be certain that the template used to create this pages is including the <title> tag and that it matches.

Comment: So the parsed pages are under your control too? if yes, are you sure, that the complete title-element is within the first 500 characters(500 is not that much)

Comment: Accessible, but not under my control. If it weren't in the first 500 characters (extremely likely it is) the explode() would either produce an incorrect string or an error.  Neither of these take place. Also, the opening <title> tag will **always** start at the 79th character, so for the entire tag to not fit within the first 500 characters the title itself would need to be over 400 characters long. @Dr.Molle

Comment: `set_time_limit()` has no effect when your PHP is under safe mode. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php That is the reason your script stops before the end. The only work-around I can think of is a complete rewrite of your web scrapping in JS with AJAX calls, then sending the results in POST to a PHP script.

Comment: @mytskine phpinfo() displays safe_mode as being off. It may also be worth noting that safe_mod is deprecated in version 5.3.0

Comment: Can you show us the contents of $products to test it on our own?

Comment: $products is an array of HTML elements returned by simplehtmldom when parsing these pages for a link of a certain class. It's got over a hundred indexes and I am not sure how best to provide it on SO so maybe I could include a `var_dump()` or `print_r()` of it in my question?

Comment: In order to (hopefully) reduce memory usage I moved $products to contain only a smaller subset of the full array at any time. Instead I included my script code so you can better understand what $products would contain.